# Using JavaScript to target the image alt

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a responsive slideshow that was using just numbers as the nav below the images. I need to replace the numbers with text. I currently have the text as the image alt, but I'm having heaps of trouble targeting the text. I know very little JS, which I'm guessing is the issue :)

Here's the pager code:

```
 //pager
 if (settings.pager) {
      var tabMarkup = [];
      $slide.each(function (i) {
        var n = i + 1;

        var images = $("#slider2 li img");

        tabMarkup +=
          "<li>" +
          "<a href='#' class='" + slideClassPrefix + n + "'>" + images.eq(i).attr("alt") + "</a>" +
          "</li>";
      });
      $pager.append(tabMarkup);

      $tabs = $pager.find("a");

      // Inject pager
      if (options.controls) {
        $(settings.controls).append($pager);
      } else {
        $this.after($pager);
      }

      // Select pager item
      selectTab = function (idx) {
        $tabs
          .closest("li")
          .removeClass(activeClass)
          .eq(idx)
          .addClass(activeClass);
      };
    }
```

And here are the images:

```
 <ul class="rslides" id="slider2">
  <li><img src="1.jpg" alt="Alt Sample" /></li>
  <li><img src="2.jpg" alt="Unlock Your Potential" /></li>
  <li><img src="3.jpg" alt="Enable Your Brand" /></li>
  <li><img src="4.jpg" alt="Lean On Our Expertise" /></li>
</ul>
```

I added "Bit" to the nav so I could find it :) n is pulling the correct number of the image. Obviously I need to take out "Bit" and replace "n" with the image alt. Any suggestions?

---

Update:

I'm using [this](https://github.com/viljamis/ResponsiveSlides.js) plugin (wish I could write something like this myself!). I've tried adding variable targeting the alt attribute, but they all come back undefined. Maybe I'm putting it in the wrong place?

---

Final Update: I modified the original code to show the changes. Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm guessing that there's some info in the `$slide` variable but I don't know what it's got in it. Which plugin are you using to get your slideshow or have you built it yourself?

Comment: You can get the `alt` text with jquery by doing `$(selector).attr('alt')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array but concatenate strings

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/xygc5/)

```
  var tabMarkup = []; // an array
  var images = $("#slider2 li img");
  $slide.each(function (i) { // assuming $slide is a collection
    tabMarkup.push(
      "<li>" +
      "<a href='#' class='" + slideClassPrefix + (i+1) + "'>" + 
      (i+1) +":" +images.eq(i).attr("alt") +"</a>" +
      "</li>");
  });
  $pager.append(tabMarkup.join(""));
```

Comment: This doesn't answer his question.

Comment: It at least attempts to now. :)

Comment: Ahem... WHat do you want then?  - I fixed the array and now take the alt attribute from the existing image - what did you expect to have to change?

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the n and get the alt attribute by using [`.attr(name)`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). The `$(this)` in your `.each` loop refers to the current item, use that to get the attribute:

```js
 // ...
 $slides.each(function() () {
     var n = $(this).attr('alt');

     // ...
 });
 // ...
```

Comment: I tried this but it returned undefined. I put it between where the variable n is defined and and tabmarkup.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector could be something like so:  `$('img[alt="Enable Your Brand"]')`